# AZ LAWYERS - Court Order For Death Certificate

Tags: death, arizona

My ex-husband passed away, and in our divorce decree I was awarded a portion of his pension. I need a copy of his death certificate for the company servicing the pension. I sent a copy of the divorce decree to Maricopa County Vital Records, but they will not give me one as I "do not qualify".

What type of attorney do I need (Family? Estate?) to file for a court order for a copy of his death certificate? I am on a very limited income, so I cannot afford a big legal bill.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What should happen is that the executor of his estate will provide a copy to the company servicing his pension.